# My custom android keyboard app, using visual studio and c#, is drawing at the top of the screen, not the bottom

Tags: c#, android, keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard, but when I select the keyboard on my device, it draws at the top of the screen instead of the bottom, effectively bocking out the input I'm using the keyboard to write to.

I've tried setting the gravity in the layout parameters as well as relative layout in the keyboar_layout.xml file. It refuses to draw on the bottom. I had been using the now obsolete Keyboardview for my keyboard, and that was working fine. But when I switched to use View.IOnTouchListener, this is when it started not drawing at the bottom. In my oncreateview I have some of my attempt fixing it commented out, but either way(if it isn't commented out) it still draws to the top of the screen.

Here is keyboard_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />

    <NewKeyboard.CustomKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>

Here is the manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourcompanyname.NewKeyboard" 
    android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:label="NewKeyboard">
        <service android:name=".MyInputMethodService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
                 android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
Here is method.xml: 
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <subtype
        android:label="@string/subtype_en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard"
        android:imeSubtypeExtraValue="AsciiCapable,EmojiCapable,SupportTouchPosition" />
</input-method>

CustomKeyboardview.cs:
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace NewKeyboard
{
    public class Key
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public RectF Rect { get; set; }
    }

    [Register("com.yourcompanyname.NewKeyboard.CustomKeyboardView")]
    public class CustomKeyboardView : View, View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        private List<Key> keys;
        private Paint keyPaint;
        private Paint labelPaint;

        public MyInputMethodService InputMethodService { get; set; }

        public CustomKeyboardView(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected CustomKeyboardView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            // Create the keys from the context
            keys = KeyboardLoader.CreateKeysList(Context);

            // Initialize the Paint objects for drawing keys and labels
            keyPaint = new Paint { Color = Color.LightGray };
            labelPaint = new Paint { Color = Color.Black, TextSize = 40 };

            // Set the OnTouchListener for this view
            SetOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);

            // Draw the keys
            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                canvas.DrawRoundRect(key.Rect, 5, 5, keyPaint);
                canvas.DrawText(key.Label, key.Rect.Left + key.Rect.Width() / 2 - labelPaint.MeasureText(key.Label) / 2, key.Rect.Top + key.Rect.Height() / 2 + labelPaint.TextSize / 2, labelPaint);
            }
        }

        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down || e.Action == MotionEventActions.Move)
            {
                // Find the key that was touched
                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    if (key.Rect.Contains((int)e.GetX(), (int)e.GetY()))
                    {
                        // Trigger the appropriate key action
                        var ic = InputMethodService.CurrentInputConnection;
                        switch (key.Code)
                        {
                            case -1: // Shift
                                // Toggle caps and update the keyboard
                                break;
                            case -4: // Done
                                ic.SendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Down, Keycode.Enter));
                                break;
                            case -5: // Delete
                                ic.DeleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                                break;
                            default:
                                char code = (char)key.Code;
                                ic.CommitText(code.ToString(), 1);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public static class KeyboardLoader
    {
        public static List<Key> CreateKeysList(Context context)
        {
            var keys = new List<Key>();

            float keyWidth = 0.1f * Resources.System.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
            float keyHeight = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 60, context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

            float x = 0;
            float y = 0;

            int[][] keyCodes = new int[][]
            {
            new int[] { 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48 },
            new int[] { 113, 119, 101, 114, 116, 121, 117, 105, 111, 112 },
            new int[] { 97, 115, 100, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, -2 },
            new int[] { -1, 122, 120, 99, 118, 98, 110, 109, 46, -3 },
            new int[] { 44, 47, 32, -5, -4 }
            };

            string[][] keyLabels = new string[][]
            {
            new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" },
            new string[] { "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p" },
            new string[] { "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "# @" },
            new string[] { "CAPS", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ".", "? ! :" },
            new string[] { ",", "/", "SPACE", "DEL", "DONE" }
            };

            for (int row = 0; row < keyCodes.Length; row++)
            {
                x = 0;
                for (int col = 0; col < keyCodes[row].Length; col++)
                {
                    var key = new Key
                    {
                        Code = keyCodes[row][col],
                        Label = keyLabels[row][col],
                        Rect = new RectF(x, y, x + keyWidth, y + keyHeight)
                    };

                    Console.WriteLine($"Creating key: Code: {key.Code}, Label: {key.Label}, Rect: {key.Rect}");
                    keys.Add(key);
                    x += keyWidth;
                }
                y += keyHeight;
            }

            return keys;
        }
      
    }
}

MainActivity.cs:
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;

namespace NewKeyboard
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HowToUse_layout);
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}

And finally MyInputMethodService.cs:
using Android.Content;
using Android.InputMethodServices;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Widget;
using Keycode = Android.Views.Keycode;

namespace NewKeyboard
{
    [Register("com.yourcompanyname.NewKeyboard.MyInputMethodService")]
    public class MyInputMethodService : InputMethodService
    {
        private View layout;
        private CustomKeyboardView keyboardView;
        public override void OnComputeInsets(Insets outInsets)
        {
            base.OnComputeInsets(outInsets);
                outInsets.ContentTopInsets = outInsets.VisibleTopInsets;
        }

        public override bool OnEvaluateFullscreenMode()
        {
            return false;
        }
        public override View OnCreateInputView()
        {
            layout = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.keyboard_layout, null);
            keyboardView = layout.FindViewById<CustomKeyboardView>(Resource.Id.keyboard);
            keyboardView.InputMethodService = this;

            //LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            //layoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom;
            //layout.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

            return layout;
        }

        public override View OnCreateCandidatesView()
        {
            // Return null if you don't need a candidates view
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you figured out to make a basic Input Method that the user can select in the IME picker? I have been trying for weeks, but nothing does it. Alternatively, can you make your source code available? If you successfully created a custom keyboard (or any input method), I would love to take a look. Thanks!